# AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Missing where attribute in the options parameter

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am trying to Update my dataabase its not giving any error but its not updating in the database

Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `title`, `slug`, `content`, `sorting`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Pages` AS `Page` WHERE `Page`.`id` = '52';

Executing (default): SELECT `id`, `title`, `slug`, `content`, `sorting`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Pages` AS `Page` WHERE `Page`.`id` = 'about-uss';

**My Model Name is Page and when i am trying to get in the Edit form i am printing those values and its working all Fine**

Thanks

```
        var where={
            id:req.params.id
        };
        var values={
            title,slug,content

        };
        var errors = req.validationErrors();

        if (errors) {
            res.render('admin/edit_page', {
                errors: errors,
                title: title,
                slug: slug,
                content: content,
                id:id
            });
        } else {
            // models.Page.find({
            //     where: {
            //         id:req.params.id
            //     }         
            // })
            // .then(function(page){
            //     if(Page){
                models.Page.update(values,where)
                .then(function(){
                    title=req.body.title,
                    slug=req.body.slug,
                    content=req.body.content
                })
                .then(function(page){
                    res.render('admin/pages');
                })
                .catch(function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                })
            }
            });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are updating any model, you should have a proper set values as key values pairs as same way you define your conditions. You have to set optional multi option to true if your purpose to update multiple. You should log the result which is returned by update function.

```
var values = {title: 'some title' , content : 'P' };
var condition = { where :{id: 2} }; 
options = { multi: true };

models.Page.update(values, condition , options)
. then(function(upresult) {} )
```

Comment: it is returning me this value [0] when i tried to do res.json(page)  here is the link for my code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50011964/my-database-in-not-updating-in-sequelize here is my code which i updated according to you

Comment: Hi, I think you have to do two things first. Firstly execute a row query in your database and check whether update operation is working properly. Ex: update Page_table set  title='a', slug='b', content ='c' where id=1. Secondly please log all your req. body and req. param values and check anything out of those becomes null or empty. Could you please comment the req.param.id, req. body. title etc. values here?

Answer (score 0):

To update all the rows at once, provide a `where` with an empty object.
Check the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55388332/7668448