# My database in not updating in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

i am trying to use this code to update my values but when i res.json it gives me [0] any one who can help me with this problem. Thanks in advance.

```
          var condition={
                where:
                {id:req.params.id}
            };
            var values={
                title:req.body.title,
                slug:req.body.slug,
                content:req.body.content
            };
            options={multi:true};
            var errors = req.validationErrors();

            if (errors) {
                res.render('admin/edit_page', {
                    errors: errors,
                    title: title,
                    slug: slug,
                    content: content,
                    id:id
                });
            } else {
                // models.Page.find({
                //     where: {
                //         id:req.params.id
                //     }         
                // })
                // .then(function(page){
                //     if(Page){
                    models.Page.update(values,condition,options)

                    .then(function(page){
                        res.render('admin/pages/edit-page');
                    })
                    .catch(function(err){
                        console.log(err);
                    })
                }
                });
```

Comment: In the current code, you are running update on the `Model` and not on the `object`. So if you have a class method `update`, please show here.

The commented code where you find an object and then run an update, it should work except a typo where is should me `page` and not `Page` inside `if` block. If not, please share the error you see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the **[doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/class/lib/model.js~Model.html#static-method-update)** update accepts only 2 params and in your function you are sending 3

Change this :

```
models.Page.update(values,condition,options)
```

To :

```
models.Page.update(values,{ ...condition, ...options }) // ES6 sprade operator
```

Comment: Now i am getting this error I have changed the line to this  
                   models.Page.update(values,{ condition,  options})

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Missing where attribute in the options parameter

Comment: Hi, I think you have to do two things first. Firstly execute a row query in your database and check whether update operation is working properly. Ex: update Page_table set  title='a', slug='b', content ='c' where id=1. Secondly please log all your req. body and req. param values and check anything out of those becomes null or empty. Could you please comment the req.param.id, req. body. title etc. values here?